# Библиотека Poco

Tags: poco, c++

Имел ли кто-нибудь дело с библиотекой [Poco](http://pocoproject.org/)? Если да, то какие впечатления, особенно со стороны надежности и быстродействия.

Comment: +1. Очень интересует сравнение с Qt...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Есть один проект в разработке и один разработанный на поддержке где Poco используется в качестве фреймворка. Впечатления в целом положительные, библиотека разработана в "тру ООП вей" даже "java вей" с умеренный использованием шаблонов, потому глубокого знания С++ не требует.

Быстродействие - в качестве контейнеров использует STL, а в остальном мест требовательных к производительности нет =)

Надежность - в целом библиотека построена на общеизвестных паттернах, потому архитектурных косяков нет. А если что-то идет не так можно запросто самому разобраться.
Из минусов стоит отметить:

В библиотеке очень много глобальных статических объектов-синглтонов. Собственно куча проблем с порядком их инициализации, который как известно не определен. Из-за этого всплывают НЕОЖИДАННЫЕ ошибки (для ознакомления - некорректно работающий семпл по логгированию). Разработчики знают, но ничего не делают. Лечится ручными патчами.

"Магическая" Poco::Net - непонятно почему 2 итерации по написанию подсистемы tcp транспорта НЕОЖИДАННО отказывались работать. В детали вдаваться не буду, но в итоге от нее отказались в пользу няшной boost::asio.

Из плюсов:

Мощная система логгирования.

NDC - позволяет выводить стек при исключения а-ля управляемый код.

Высокоуровневые структуры для многопоточности.

В целом хороший легковесный фреймворк без ГУИ. Особенно хорошо идет в сочетании с MFC, которому Poco может придать весьма благородный вид.

Poco используем около 2х лет, задавайте свои ответы.

Comment: Спасибо. Открыл Poco буквально пару дней назад в ходе поисков кроссплатформенного способа запуска внешних приложений. И очень удивился, что такая замечательная библиотека так мало известна.

Comment: Можно у вас проконсультироваться по библиотеке poco?
